# ionic cordova build android doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova

Everything was working fine when I was running my hybrid mobile app through the terminal. For some reason though I am getting this error.

```
✖ Running command - failed!

    [ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
    You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above 
    directly.

    [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit  
    code 1):

    cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file

    (code=EACCES):/Users/theodosiostziomakas/desktop/
    capstone/mobile/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml

    Error: EACCES: permission denied, open
    '/Users/theodosiostziomakas/desktop/capstone/
    mobile/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml'
```

I removed the android folder ie ionic cordova platform remove android and later added it, but still I have the same error. Any advice? I looked in different answers but none of them worked for me.

Thanks,

Theo.

Comment: Have you tried giving permission to your root folder of project ?

Comment: Nope. I don't remember doing that. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: which os you are using ? Linux or any other ?

Comment: I am using Mac Pro with OS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: Try this using terminal *chmod -R 777 your_folder*.

Comment: I am adding this but nothing happened. chmod -R 777 cd desktop/capstone/mobile

Comment: I put this chmod -R 777 cd desktop/capstone/mobile/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml
but operation is not permitted.